# How can Java 8 forEach be used on a String object to encode the values?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to write the equivalent of the following using Java 8 ForEach to encode an array of Strings.

```
public static void encode(String... stringsToEncode) {
  for (int i = 0; i < stringsToEncode.length; i++) {
     stringsToEncode[i] = URLEncoder.encode(stringsToEncode[i], "UTF-8");
  }
}
// stringsToEncode = 10+111569+++8 as expected.
```

I have implemented the following:

```
public static void encodeUsingForEach(String... stringsToEncode)
  List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.asList(stringsToEncode);
  listOfStrings.forEach(s -> {
    try {
      s = URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      throw new AssertionError("UTF-8 is unknown");
    }
 });
}
// listOfStrings = [10 11, 156, 9   8]
```

What am I missing so that the output of encodeUsingForEach() is equivalent to that of the encode() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't replace a value using `forEach()`, because it only *consumes* objects without *returning* them. The reassignment inside the lambda effectively does nothing because [arguments are passed by value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1553851). Instead, try using a stream to map the values and produce a new list:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.stream(stringsToEncode)
        .map(s -> {
            try {
                return URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new AssertionError("UTF-8 is unknown");
            }
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Just as a note, instead of using `"UTF-8"` a more flexible way would be to use the corresponding constant defined in `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html)) inside the package `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`.

Comment: @Zabuza Unfortunately, `URLEncoder` doesn't accept a `Charset` object.

Comment: Oh, what a pity.

Comment: @Zabuza Yeah, I'm surprised it hasn't been updated. I suppose you could still use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()`, but no way to avoid that ugly try/catch.

Comment: Could you add an explanation why the code of OP does not work? I mean it compiles and I could imagine that he is confused why the lambda doesn't do its job.

Comment: @Zabuza It's hard to know why OP thinks it should work, but I've added a bit of explanation.

Comment: More sugar to the rescue (method reference)!

    List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.stream(stringsToEncode).map(this::encode).collect(Collectors.toList());
  
`private String encode(String s) {
        try {
            return URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("UTF-8 is unknown");
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

In lambda expression the s is one of the members of the list and list is pointing to that location in the memory. So if the s was an object and you changed some fields of that every thing would go right way but now you are replacing the address of object stored in s without updating in the list. So by doing this replacement you are just losing the refrence nothing more.